# How do I count I/O paths in a virtual machine?

Tags: linux, postgresql, io, vps

How many I/O paths would a virtual machine -- like an EC2 instance or a Linode instance -- have available? I'm interested in learning more about this because I don't know an appropriate value for PostgreSQL's `effective_io_concurrency` setting. Thanks!

Comment: What do you call an "I/O path"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't know what's behind the mountpoints of your virtual machines. So the best thing you can and, actually, should do: test [the performance of the disks alone](http://stu.mp/2009/12/disk-io-and-throughput-benchmarks-on-amazons-ec2.html) and then testing it with different values of [`effective_io_concurrency`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-EFFECTIVE-IO-CONCURRENCY).

I would took each `/dev/*` device that is used in your mountpoints as a separate IO path, at least this can be a good start.

I also think, that this configuration parameter has more value on the dedicated physical servers, rather then virtual ones (provided externally of course).